# java combination requestion

Tags: java, arrays

three integer arrays a [], b [], c []. The array length is variable and the numbers in each array can not be repeated. The number in a [] is taken from 0 to 13 and the length is at least 9, and the number in b [] is taken from a [], and the number in c [] is taken from b []. From the three arrays to take 9 numbers, each number in each array  can only take 1 times, get the number of combination.

example1:

```
a[]={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}

b[]={1,2}

c[]={1}

return totalCount=6;
```

because ('a' means from arrays a[])

```
  0,1a,2a,3,4,5,6,7,8;

  0,1a,2b,3,4,5,6,7,8;

  0,1b,2a,3,4,5,6,7,8;

  0,1b,2b,3,4,5,6,7,8;

  0,1c,2a,3,4,5,6,7,8;

  0,1c,2b,3,4,5,6,7,8;
```

example2:

```
  a[]={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12}

  b[]={0,1,2,3,4}

  c[]={0,1,2,3,4}

  return totalCount=47985
```

i have done some work but it only worked while the length of c[] is 0 or the length of a[]==9

```
int num=0;
    if(a.size()<9){
        num = 0;
    }else{
        if(b.size()==0){
                num= combineNum(a.size(),9).intValue();
        }else{
            if(three.size()==0){
                    num=combineNum(a.size(),9).intValue();
                    for(int i=1;i<=b.size();i++){
                        num=num+combineNum(a.size()-i,9-i).intValue()
                                *combineNum(b.size(),b.size()-i).intValue();
                    }
            }else{
                if(c.size()==b.size()){
                    if(a.size()==9){
                        num=(int)Math.pow(3,c.size());
                    }else{
                        num=combineNum(a.size(),9).intValue();
                        for(int i=1;i<=b.size();i++){
                            if(i==1){
                                num=num+combineNum(a.size()-i,9-i).intValue()
                                        *combineNum(2*b.size(),i).intValue();
                            }else{
                                num=num+combineNum(a.size()-i,9-i).intValue()
                                        *(combineNum(2*b.size(),i).intValue()-
                                        b.size()*combineNum(2*b.size()-2*(i-1),i-1).intValue());
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }else {
                    if(a.size()==9){
                        num= (int)(Math.pow(3,c.size())*Math.pow(2,b.size()-c.size())
                                *combineNum(a.size(),9).intValue());
                    }else{
                        num=-1;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return num;
```

could anybody help me?

i need get 9 numbers from the three arrays, number can be from any arrays,but can not be repeated . just like my code ,i have compute the count while c.length==0 or a.length==9.anybody has any ideas about the rest of the situation?

Comment: do you even have a question??

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it´s a homework dump without any effort shown by OP to solve the task on his own

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem.
put my code below

```
public static long getRen9Numbers(boolean[] winChecked,
                                  boolean[] tieChecked,boolean[] lossChecked) throws Exception {
    TreeSet<Integer> first=new TreeSet<>();
    TreeSet<Integer> second=new TreeSet<>();
    TreeSet<Integer> three=new TreeSet<>();
    for(int i=0;i<winChecked.length;i++){
        if(winChecked[i]){
            first.add(i);
        }
    }
    for(int i=0;i<tieChecked.length;i++){
        if(tieChecked[i]){
            if(first.contains(i)){
                second.add(i);
            }else{
                first.add(i);
            }
        }
    }
    for(int i=0;i<lossChecked.length;i++){
        if(lossChecked[i]){
            if(first.contains(i)){
                if(second.contains(i)){
                    three.add(i);
                }else{
                    second.add(i);
                }
            }else{
                first.add(i);
            }
        }
    }
    long num=0;
    if(first.size()<9){
        num = 0;
    }else{
        if(second.size()==0){
            num= combineNum(first.size(),9).intValue();
        }else{
            if(three.size()==0){
                for(int i=0;i<=second.size();i++){
                  num=num+combineNum(second.size(),i).longValue()*
                          combineNum(first.size()-i,9-i).longValue();
                }
            }else{
                for(int i=0;i<=three.size();i++){
                    long count1=0;
                    for(int j=0;j<=second.size()-i;j++){
                        count1=count1+combineNum(second.size()-i,j).longValue()*
                                combineNum(first.size()-(j+i),9-(j+i)).longValue();
                    }
                    num=num+combineNum(three.size(),i).longValue()*count1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return num;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Count how many times you have each number repeated and multiply them, those are quite simple maths

a[]={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}

b[]={1,2}

c[]={1}

You have 3 ones and 2 twos, so you will have:

1(0)*3(possible ones)*2(possible twos)*1(3)*1(4)*1(5)*1(6)*1(7)*1(8) = 6

Comment: no it's not simple , first , i need choose 9 numbers from three arrays ,second,numbers in the nine can not be reapted,at last ,the length of a[] can be 9~13 and the length of b[] or c[] is variable

Comment: Since Array hasn't a contains method, you have two options : 
1. Do a for over the first array taking its numbers and two nested for checking if b or c contains the number.
2. List<Integer> aList = Arrays.asList(a); (same with b and c) and iterate over aList checking bList.contains(number); (or cList)

You will need 2 variables, one for a single for iteration count and a second one with the result of
total *= iterationCount

Comment: i cant get all combination while the length became large @Aldeguer

Comment: just like example 2

Comment: In fact, are you sure example 2 is correct? I think the result would be 243 since you have 3*3*3*3*3*1*1*1*1*1*1*1

Comment: im sure,this is a combination question,just as  i get 9 numbers from a[],count=C(13,9)

Comment: a[]={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12}

b[]={0,1,2,3,4}

c[]={0,1,2,3,4}

0, 1, 2, 3, 4 = 3 times = 3^5

5..12 = 1 time = 1^8

As I remember, the number of possible combinations would be the multiply of these, how did you get 47985?

Comment: count=C(a.length+b.length+c.length,9)-?=817190-?. i dont know how mach should i  subtract